# Why is the Schmitt Trigger output fed back to the current source in NE 566 (VCO)?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source, schmitt-trigger

[image: NE 566]

I understand the working of the circuit, a Voltage Control Oscillator, except the part where the inverted square wave from the Schmitt Trigger gets fed to the Constant current source/sink. Pins 5 and 6 are maintained at the same voltage so when the modulation i/p voltage is increased, the pin 6 voltage also increases => Constant current decreases => Decreasing charging current for capacitor => A longer charging time => Wider pulses.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could hazard a guess about the Schmitt trigger feedback to the Current source/sink.

Comment: It switches the current direction.

Comment: The feedback from the Schmitt trigger output is essential to make the circuit oscillate. Without it the circuit would get stuck in a certain state C1 charged or C1 discharged. The feedback makes it oscillate between those states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current source can be switched to operate either as a current source or a current sink.

When it sources a current the capacitor C1 gets charged, when it sinks a current C1 gets discharged.

Having a constant current results in a constant slope and produces the triangular waveform. To get a rising and falling edge the current needs to change direction.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense... I didn't think about the source/sink needing a signal to switch between the two.